# How does Wireshark interpret hex value?

Tags: python, wireshark

Wireshark detects an 8 byte field in a packet with the hex value of (40 34 00 00 00 00 00 00). It's ascii value is @4 but decoded it is 20. Currently I'm using a private protocol and I'm sending the packets from a python script. They value of 20 is correct, as in the python script.
 How is this conversion made?

Comment: I think you'll need to have a look at the source code to determine that.

Comment: For us to help you, you should edit your question to include the python script.

Comment: If you want that wireshark decodes your private protocol, you should to develop that. If not, wireshark only will show the raw data in hex.